# Vertical center image without pos:absolute inside pos:relative

Tags: html, css

The header of my blog shows the title with an image behind. I want that this image have it's own height *until* it gets bigger than `50vh` (50% of user viewport).

But the normal behavior is the image be cropped from bottom and I want that the image be cropped from top *and* bottom (in other words: I want the image vertically centered).

I could do this with `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%)` but in that case `img` should be `position: absolute` and that would make the header always with the same height (since the image couldn't set the height of the element).

This is my code:

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="date">
    Posted 10 hours ago
  </div>

  <h1>Meet the all new Jaguar F-type</h1>

  <img src="http://read.bi/2cMrdUI" />
</div>
```

On the following example, please **resize jsfiddle width** as much as you can. That will be easier to understand.

> https://jsfiddle.net/jkc3L13g/

```css
.header {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 150px;
    max-height: 70vh;
    .date {
      z-index: 10;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
    }
    h1 {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 10;
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
}

/* Just to style.. */
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
.header { color: white; text-shadow: black 0 1px 2px }
hr { margin: 2rem 0 ; }
code { font-size: 1.25rem; padding: 1px 2px; background: lightyellow; }
h1, .date { margin: 10px }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="date">
    Posted 10 hours ago
  </div>

  <h1>Meet the all new Jaguar F-type</h1>
            
  <img src="http://read.bi/2cMrdUI" />
</div>

<hr />

<p>
Resize window width as much as you can.
</p>
<p>
When <code>img</code> gets too big and <code>.header</code> starts limitating to <code>70vh</code>, <code>img</code> should "vertically centralize".
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<img>` tag, use the image as a CSS background image for `.header`, then set `background-size: cover` and `background-position: center` (this will align the image), but you also need to set a fixed height for `.header`.

This will look a bit different, hope it can help you.

```
background-image: url(http://read.bi/2cMrdUI);
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jkc3L13g/1/

```css
.header {
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 150px;
  height: 70vh; /* fixed height */

  background-image: url(http://read.bi/2cMrdUI);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;

  .date {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
  }
  h1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}

/* Just to style.. */
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
.header { color: white; text-shadow: black 0 1px 2px }
hr { margin: 2rem 0 ; }
code { font-size: 1.25rem; padding: 1px 2px; background: lightyellow; }
h1, .date { margin: 10px }
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="date">
    Posted 10 hours ago
  </div>

  <h1>Meet the all new Jaguar F-type</h1>

</div>

<hr />

<p>
  Resize window width as much as you can.
</p>
<p>
  When <code>img</code> gets too big and <code>.header</code> starts limitating to <code>70vh</code>, <code>img</code> should "vertically centralize".
</p>
```

Comment: That is, in fact, a solution – but it is not SEO/accessibility friendly, since I can't use ALT.